# How to compute the summation $\sum_{x\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{-\pi x^2/s^2}$?

Tags: summation, normal-distribution

A discrete normal distribution problem: Suppose we want to sample an integer from
$\rho(x) = \frac{1}{s}e^{-\frac{\pi x^2}{s^2}}$, then a natural idea is: sample a real then round it to nearest integer, in this way, the probability of zero is $\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}\rho(x)dx = erf(\sqrt{\pi}/2s)=1/s - \Omega(1/s^3)$.

However, the discrete normal distribution is defined as: $\frac{\rho(x)}{\sum_{x\in\mathbb{Z}}\ \ \rho(x)}$，the probability of zero is $\frac{1}{\sum_{x\in\mathbb{Z}}\ \ e^{-\frac{\pi x^2}{s^2}}}$, then how to compute it? What does the series expansion of it look like?

Comment: You want to know about $\,\theta_3(0,q)\,$ which is a [theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function).

Comment: This is a bit of a plug, but you may want to look at https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.00010 (there are results and bounds on the pdf, as well as explanations about how to sample exactly from the discrete gaussian).